# Selecting rows from pandas dataframe limited by count per column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe defined as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':    [11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 31, 32, 33], 
                   'class': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'count': [2, 2, 2 ,2 ,1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
```

[image]

For each class, I'd like to select top `n` rows where `n` is specified by count column. The expected output from the above dataframe would be like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Define: "few rows" is that one or two, 20 percent, or 50 percent?

Comment: The number of rows I'd like to keep is specified by value of the count column for the corresponding class.

Comment: So you want the lowest `count` of each class based on ID?

Comment: Updated the question description to be more accurate.

Comment: and by top `n` you mean ordered by ID ascending, right?

Comment: Yes @MattMessersmith

Comment: What if the count column is different for the same 'class' value?

Comment: That's not possible for the dataframe I have @payne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
In [771]: df.groupby('class').apply(
                     lambda x: x.head(x['count'].iloc[0])
                  ).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[771]:
   id class  count
0  11     A      2
1  12     A      2
2  21     B      1
3  31     C      2
4  32     C      2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
(df.groupby('class', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x.head(x['count'].iloc[0])))
```

Output:

```
   id class  count
0  11     A      2
1  12     A      2
4  21     B      1
6  31     C      2
7  32     C      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cumcount`

```
df[(df.groupby('class').cumcount()+1).le(df['count'])]
Out[150]: 
  class  count  id
0     A      2  11
1     A      2  12
4     B      1  21
6     C      2  31
7     C      2  32
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which groups by *class* then then looks at the first value in the smaller dataframe and returns the corresponding rows.

```
def func(df_):
    count_val = df_['count'].values[0]
    return df_.iloc[0:count_val]

df.groupby('class', group_keys=False).apply(func)
```

returns

```
  class  count  id
0     A      2  11
1     A      2  12
4     B      1  21
6     C      2  31
7     C      2  32
```